# How to call IdentityServer UserManager method from web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I Need to initiate the password reset from my web api. I have identity server application and web api applications separately. I use OIDC client to communicate with identity server. With this client I can only call signin, signout and some standard methods.

What I need is to generate password reset token and get the reset token in API.

I have tried to include `'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core'` in my webapi core layer which have all the entities. But I get

> Unable to resolve service for type 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore1[Application.Core.Entities.User]
>   while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager

## code

```
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

private async Task<string> GeneratePasswordResetLinkAsync(User user)
{
    string token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    return token;
}
```

I've also tried adding below code in startup Injection
`services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>, UserManager<User>>();`

What is the proper way of injecting UserManager in my web api ?

Comment: Do you create custom user class which inherits  `IdentityUser` ?

Comment: How are you storing users?  If you are using asp.net identity it should already have the ability to reset a users password you just need to hit the correct endpoint from your web api.

Comment: No I'm using the existing web api entity user call

Comment: I'm using vuex oidc. as i did some research i couldn't able to find any endpoints to reset the password

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure asp.net core identity in the Startup class of you web api. Unfortunately you can not simply call `services.AddIdentity(...` in ConfigureServices because behind the scenes a cookie-based authentication scheme is registered and set as the default challenge scheme, as you can see in the code [here for asp.net core 2.2](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a64688d8e192cacffda9440e8725c1ed41a30cf/src/Identity/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L45-L76)
or [here for asp.et core 3.1](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.3/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L44-L76).
Thus the solution I end up with is to copy & update AddIdentity method like this:

For ASP.NET CORE 2.2:

```cs
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentityForWebApi<TUser, TRole>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
    where TUser : class
    where TRole : class
{
    // Hosting doesn't add IHttpContextAccessor by default
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    // Identity services
    services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TRole>, RoleValidator<TRole>>();

    // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
    services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator, TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>>();
    services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TRole>>();

    if (setupAction != null)
    {
        services.Configure(setupAction);
    }

    return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TRole), services);
}
```

For ASP.NET CORE 3.1:

```cs
static IdentityBuilder AddIdentityForWebApi<TUser, TRole>(
      this IServiceCollection services,
      Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
      where TUser : class
      where TRole : class
    {
      // Hosting doesn't add IHttpContextAccessor by default
      services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

      // Identity services
      services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
      services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TRole>, RoleValidator<TRole>>();

      // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
      services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
      services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator, TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<IUserConfirmation<TUser>, DefaultUserConfirmation<TUser>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>>();
      services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TRole>>();

      if (setupAction != null)
      {
        services.Configure(setupAction);
      }

      return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TRole), services);
    }
```

Then you should call AddIdentityForWebApi in the Startup of your web api application.
This will register the UserManager and it will now be injected in your controller's constructor.

Then you should configure Data Protection API (DPAPI) properly so that the token generated by your web api (when you call `_userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync...` from your question) could be unprotected by your identity server application.

So I set the "DPAPI application name" across the two applications, in both `ConfigureServices` methods:

```cs
services.AddDataProtection()
  .dataProtectionBuilder.SetApplicationName("YOUR_DPAPI_APPLICATION_NAME");
```

For production, in a web farm environment, you will have to share the DPAPI keys. Depending on your situation you have several options.

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview) for more details on how to configure DPAPI.

I have tested on Kestrel running Windows, I am not sure about IIS.

Comment: @ragavendhran-n, did you get a chance to read my answer?
I am using this in my project successfully and I would be interested to get your feedback. What do you think?

Comment: @ragavendhran-n, was my answer useful/correct? I believe my answer is the correct one. If so, would you mind mark it as the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The injection code does not look correct.  Try changing it to

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager<Application.Core.Entities.User>>();
```